# Action does not apply to any resource(s) in statement - how to allow users to only list sub folders named with their IAM name?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-policies

So I was wanting to have folders that would be named the same as a logged in IAM user - so if I had a user named "Bob", the key structure would be:

```
- My Bucket
    - Bob
        - Bob's stuff
    - Mary
        - Mary's stuff
```

and I wanted a policy to prevent Bob from being able to look into Mary's folder and likewise for Bob.

Initially, I tried:

```
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": "*",
"Action": "s3:ListBucket",
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/${aws:username}"
```

but it would throw

> Action does not apply to any resource(s) in statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this goal, having this in the policy as a section:

```
"Effect": "Allow",
"Principal": "*",
"Action": "s3:ListBucket",
"Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket",
"Condition": {
    "StringLike": {
         "s3:prefix": "${aws:username}/*"
    }
}
```

worked for me.

Here are some [example policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-policies-s3.html) that may help, for in the future.